# Creating paired bar graph in ggplot with error bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, tidyverse

Is there a way to create a bar graph in ggplot that pairs bars together based on their group? I can't get the order on the x axis to be correct. It should be (going from left to right) 40 ng/mL then 20 ng/mL but for some reason its doing 20 ng/mL first. Also, is there a way to add the error bars to the corresponding bar on the bar graph? Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
    data <- data.frame(Group=rep(c("Control", "Experimental"),each=2),
                         Concs=rep(c("40 ng/mL", "20 ng/mL"), 2),
                         Absorbance=c(0.24396666,
                                      0.186266667,
                                      0.1942,
                                 0.1627),
                         sd1=c(0.01490671,
                               0.013587617,
                               0.008195324,
                               0.016703143))
    
    ggplot(data, aes(x=Concs, y=Absorbance, fill=Group)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `reorder` `Concs` and there is a geometry called `geom_errorbar`, here an example:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Concs = fct_rev(Concs)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Concs, y=Absorbance, fill=Group, group = Group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Absorbance-sd1,ymax = Absorbance+sd1),
                position=position_dodge(1),
                width = .5)+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Experimental" = "red","Control" = "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! By the way, is there any way to specify that the Control should be colored blue and the Experimental should be colored red?

Comment: Sure, you need to add a scale element